# Attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild' (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

im trying to make a points system that gives 10 points if the player survived the round.
how it works: the player touches the part in the begining of the round and the roundvalue becomes true. when the player tps to lobby and touches the part in the lobby the value of the round becones false and he gets 10 point only if he survives.
i tried everything and i just don't understand why i got this error.
help would be appriciated! thx.

```
Players = game:GetService("Players")

local part = script.Parent
local lobbypart = workspace.LobbyPart


local inround = false
local SurvivedPoints = 10


local function givepoints(player)
    local playerstats = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats") -- problem here
    local playerpoints = playerstats:WaitForChild("Points") -- problem here
    playerpoints.Value = playerpoints.Value + SurvivedPoints
end


local function ontouched(otherPart)
    local character = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        inround = true
        print("Round begins")
    end
    local function inlobby(otherPart)
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
        if player and inround == true then
            inround = false 
            print("round ended")
            givepoints()
        end
    end
        
        
    lobbypart.Touched:Connect(inlobby)
        
end

part.Touched:Connect(ontouched)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `givePoints(player)` function you created expects you to give it a player. But when you called it, you didn't supply one. Just pass in the player object.

```lua
    local function inlobby(otherPart)
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
        if player and inround == true then
            inround = false 
            print("round ended")
            givepoints(player)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Now it says: Infinite yield possible on 'Players.idan1973.leaderstats:WaitForChild("Points")

Comment: That error usually means that there's a typo, or no object with that name. When you created the leaderstats object for points, did you set its `Name` property to be "Points".

Comment: I wrote "points" insted of "Points" thank you so much 